# ListView scroll lines blur

Tags: android, listview, optimization, lag

When I scroll my ListView the lines lag a lot.  I posted a video showing it on YouTube:

http://youtu.be/U2Za_ofrrr8

I'm wondering if anyone has had this issue even after they optimized their code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from a video but it looks like it's simply your phone's display not refreshing fast enough.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem was I had a layout within a ListView row with several buttons.  When I didn't need the buttons I was setting them to View.GONE.  When I set them to View.INVISIBLE the lag went away for the most part.